# Error during upgrade installation of my product

Tags: c#, installshield

I am expecting this is probably a really easy question but I am somewhat stuck.

I get an error when attempting to install a new release of our product over the latest existing version.  This is the error.

"A later version of "abc" is installed on this machine.  The setup cannot continue."

The version number of the original installation is 5.0.1.116 and the new is 5.1.0.138.  This is set in the Assembly and also in the InstallShield properties.  I did not modify the program code or upgrade code in InstallShield and am reasonably sure I should not be doing that.

The new version number looks to me to be higher in every aspect.  The 3rd digit is mentioned as something to use for a build number but I don't normally do that.  That could be an issue (maybe) in trying to go from Build 1 to Build 0.  I have been using this versioning schema for a while with no issues until now so I must have tripped over some setting in this one.

More Info.

- C# .Net 2.0 project.
- InstallShield 12 for installation package.
- Obfuscation is used although I tried it unobfuscated also.
- Can't think of anything else to mention.

Any ideas are tremendously welcome.

Comment: Are you running setup.exe or the .msi file to upgrade your application?

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer finally.  I found this in the DirectEditor under `ISProductConfigurationPropertyTable-Property=ProductVersion`.

Interestingly, I don't know what originally set this and don't see any other exposed place to do so.  I am probably just burnt at the moment.  If anyone does know offhand, feel free to let me know.

This could be an issue I forget for next build :)